# Why is K9999 almost identical to Tetsuo Shima?

Tags: akira, game-history

I was watching [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1YeTs5oHAwg) which shows the similarities between both characters. I suppose it must be a kind of tribute, or maybe is just a vile copy (I don't think so). Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: It looks like footage from the movie spliced into video of the game. It's clearly not from the game itself.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K9999#NESTS_Team) says

> and K9999 (pronounced K Four-Nine), a clone from Kyo entirely based on Tetsuo Shima from Akira, able to transform his arm into a long tentacle like Tetsuo's. Due to copyright issues, for the King of Fighters 2002 remake he was replaced with a similar character.

but gives no sources.

Answer (score 3):

K9999 won't appear in any future games because

1. SNK hates the character
2. He is a liable lawsuit in which the creators of *Akira* could sue SNK Playmore
3. Elioth, a Korean company helped co-create *King of Fighters 2001* and owns the rights to him
4. He was replaced in *KoF 2002 Unlimited Match* with a character called "nameless" who looks like Black Jack from the anime.

Answer (score -2):

I think K9999 is the 9999th android of "K" because it disappeared, looking for the nests hideout and destroy it because they killed the original "K" who's real name is Kryzalid.

Tetsuo Shima is just a kid who grew up poor and turned into a mutant by Akira and put into an Akira Institute, and he escaped not knowing that his infected arm must be kept stable and that's why he ended up transformed into a huge mutated ugly monster and just died.